# In magento 2 How to call phtml file in static block

Tags: magento2

I have created extension in magento 2 and i want to call `content.phtml` file from static block (from admin panel). My content template file location is

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento2\app/code\Surya\Slider\view\frontend\templates\content.phtml
```

where, magento2 is my project folder, Surya is vendor and Slider is my extension name. I want to call `content.phtml` file on homepage through static block.

For that I have created one static block called as "slider". Also, i have created widget. But i want to call content.phtml file in static block.

Answer (score 2):

try below code :

```
{{block class="Surya\Slider\Block\Slideshow" template="Surya_Slider::content.phtml"}}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: @Rohit, How do we can pass params in this added block ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code -

```
{{block class="Surya\Slider\Block\Slideshow" template="Surya_Slider::content.phtml"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to call template block in CMS static Block or CMS Page in Magento 2, then you can simply write the following code:

The skeleton code to understand :

`{{block class="<vendor_name>\<module_name>\Block\<module_name>" name="<your_block_name>" template="<vendor_name>_<module_name>::<tempate_directory>/content.phtml"}}`

Exact code :

`{{block class="Surya\Slider\Block\Slider" name="slider" template="Surya_Slider::content.phtml"}}`