# How to include a phtml file in static block magento 2?

Tags: magento2, static-block

Can somebody help me in finding How to call a phtml file in static block magento 2?

I am new to this, can you please give me full documentation for this as how to do this.I have searched and read whole stack but I couldn't understand.

The earlier question asked specifies some answer but I don't have any code folder in my magento folder in app

Thanks in advance plz

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In magento 2 How to call phtml file in static block](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38887624/in-magento-2-how-to-call-phtml-file-in-static-block)

Answer (score 0):

```
{{block class="Block Name" template="PackageName_ ModuleName::phtml file name"}}
```

Ex :- `{{block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" template="Magento_Catalog::description.phtml"}}`